# JMETER: Parallel Controller - no response data

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, aws, parallel-execution

I have defined the JDBC Connection configuration and have added multiple JDBC requests in JMeter and have added the bzm - Parallel Controller plugin. Below is the image for the setup of the parallel controller alongside the.
[image: bzm - Parallel Controller][image: bzm]

However, After adding the Controller and the JDBC requests, in the View Results Tree I am getting an Error for the parallel controller with a 200: response code. When i click on the response data it comes back empty.

When I log into my database, I am able to see the queries running in parallel but nothing is being shown on Jmeter

How could I fix the issue?
[image: request]
[image: response data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) and tick individual child sampler in order to see the response data (if any) and eventually error details if it failed for some reason:

[image]

another way is to untick the "Generate parent sample" option, this way you will see the "normal" results.

Don't forget to remove or at least disable the View Results Tree listener (as well as any other listeners) as [they don't add any value just consume the valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)

Comment: thank you, solved the issue